# User experience when CAL threshold is reached?

Tags: licensing, user-experience

I am planning on deploying a Sharepoint Standard installation with 10 concurrent users, regularly.  That is, nearly 99% of the time there will only be a handful of people using the application.  But if an event occurs at this office I may get 30 people wanting to look at the application for a quick status update.

I'm frightened of what may occur if I hit that CAL threshold and the CEO is told that he can't connect to his own application.  My question being:

1. What occurs when a CAL threshold is reached?  Will users be presented with an error?
2. Also, is it common and necessary to purchase the needed CALs for the extremely far-fetched scenarios?

Comment: I'd like to add that Microsoft's pre-sales licensing people are VERY helpful!  Just call them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft does not do concurrent licensing. You need to puchase a CAL for every user that will access SharePoint, or for every device that will access SharePoint. You may want to look at this link for more information on SharePoint licensing. http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/default.aspx

That being said there is no error. SharePoint does not track the amount of CAL's. However if you do not have enough and you are audited you could very well be fined.

Comment: I just got off the phone with MS pre-sales licensing.  You are absolutely correct.